# MySQL: Multiple tables (one time all columns, three times only a single column)

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
        FROM table_all ta
        INNER JOIN table11 ta11 
        ON ta11.column1 = ta.column1
        INNER JOIN table12 ta12
        ON ta12.column2 = ta.column2
        INNER JOIN table13 ta13
        ON ta13.column3 = ta.column3';
```

This is a sql statement of a PHP-programm that I am currently working on. It works fine actually, but I am unsatisfied with the outcome of this statement. It would be nice to have

1. *only* the content of the **table_all** and then
2. *only* the three columns of those other three tables (**table11**, **table12**, **table13**).

The **asterisk** creates some problems in this regard.

- The length of **table_all** is not known. It is able to change in size.

I tried **Union** and **multiple selects**, but only received errors. How would one deal with such a problem?

Comment: What outcome you really wanted..

Comment: Basically: table_all + ta11.column1 + ta12.column2 + ta13.column3

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying which columns do you want to get.
As you can see asterisk returns all columns.
You should use something like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ta11.column1, taa12.column2, ta13.column13 
    FROM table_all ta
    INNER JOIN table11 ta11 
    ON ta11.column1 = ta.column1
    INNER JOIN table12 ta12
    ON ta12.column2 = ta.column2
    INNER JOIN table13 ta13
    ON ta13.column3 = ta.column3';
```

I don't see a point in getting `ta11.column1`, `taa12.column2`, `ta13.column13` because these fields are already in table_all (you use these columns in Join). But you can select any columns you want that way.

Comment: They are not there. They appear in a different kind of way. Example: table_all.column1 = 1; table11.column1 = water

Comment: But when you do `INNER JOIN` you are "joining" tables (in example table_all with table11 and table12 and table13). Result is another table with all columns from all these tables. But the "joining" happens only for rows where your `ON` statements are equal (in example table_all.column1 = water and table11.column1 = water).

Comment: The thing is that I need all content of table_all as well. Not only the stuff from ther other tables. I could have easily done that with some joins. No, I need everything from table_all plus those three other columns

Comment: 'SELECT ta.*, ta11.column1, taa12.column2, ta13.column13 '

Comment: Error: #1051 unknown table ta.* / Does not work and it does not make sense, because I need the references from the content of table_all

Comment: That was just beginning of the statement. Full is: $sql = 'SELECT ta.*, ta11.column1, taa12.column2, ta13.column13 
    FROM table_all ta
    INNER JOIN table11 ta11 
    ON ta11.column1 = ta.column1
    INNER JOIN table12 ta12
    ON ta12.column2 = ta.column2
    INNER JOIN table13 ta13
    ON ta13.column3 = ta.column3';

Comment: That is embarassing. I simply had not seen this. Works fine of course. Too much code here. :) Thanks

Comment: That's fine. I would appreciate if you could accept the answer :) gl